# How to prevent folders from folding in project structure when creating a new activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a project structure in my project in Android Studio, it is always unfold, so I can see all my layouts in folders. When I create a new activity folders in project structure fold and I have to always search my layouts everytime when I create a new activity.

**How can I make folders prevent from folding when I create any activity or a fragment?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you talking about Docked Mode. Please do as follows :

[image: Solution]